Python flask not applying css style even though the browser is showing the css file in the sources panel in the development tools
My flask application is not applying css styling on my website.
Note: I have reviewed and applied all the solutions i found on stack overflow but none of them worked
I have tried all the solutions i found on the internet but still unable to solve this problem.My flask application is not applying css style.Click here to see the nesting of the Code files
As it can be seen i have made seperate directories,templates for html files and static for css files but still the problem remains
The Irony is that the browser is loading the css file but for some reason not applying the stylesBrowser loading the css file but not applying the style
I have also tried hard reload,clearing browser cache,changing browser,changing code editor(tried pycharm then shifted to VS code but the problem remained :( )
I would really appreciate some help it's been so long.
python flask code:
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

html code:
html code
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.css">
</head>

The console is showing no error in loading css file:
"E:\Pycharm Projects\hello_flask\57-Capstone-proj-Blog\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "E:\Pycharm Projects\hello_flask\57-Capstone-proj-Blog\main.py" 
 * Serving Flask app 'main'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://xxxxx
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 861-474-752
 - - [24/Jun/2024 20:45:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 - - [24/Jun/2024 20:45:06] "GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 - - [24/Jun/2024 20:45:06] "GET /static/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -


We can't help, because you have not shared the contents of index.html.

Please post code, not image of code.

I don't see a route that would serve up the css file.

Thanks for reviewing the post.I have attached the html code now @James

It doesn't make sense to include ../ paths in your HTML. All static HTML files should be served from the a directory within the application root /. If the relative parent paths are successful, you have a major problem and your app could be vulnerable to serving any file on the filesystem.

@h0r53 Thanks for your help.I have removed the " ../ " from the path, as well as changed moved the css file in and out ,also tried to move it to the same directory as the html file but of no use

The problem is not of the path/route of css file,if that was the problem the browser wouldnt load the css file,it would 've given the error : .css file not found

Hey, did you add a  tag? It is not present in the picture. What is your browser version and which browser do you use?

@efeakaroz13 Thank you for your help.To avoid unneccesary expansion of the post i only pasted the important starting bit of code.In my html file the  tag is present at the end

you didn't provide enough information but applying these might solve the issue:
Remove .. from the static file URL
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.css">

like this.
Check your folder structure
/myapp
 -app.py
 /static
   /css
     -styles.css
 /templates

Since you didn't share any python code, I can't speculate if you've overridden the original route for this file by doing something like this:
@app.route("/static/css/styles.css")

Check your path, edit your HTML code, and if you have a route like above, remove it. If it is a browser-related issue, I suggest checking the styles of the elements and sources from the developer settings.
NOTE:
This issue may occur if you directly open index.html rather than visiting the running port of the Flask app. Check the browser URL, if it starts with file:// you need to go to localhost.
Additional:
If the error persists, I suggest using a different browser.

Thank you for the help.I have tried all of this as i mentioned earlier including checking a different browser and i have attached code snippets in pictures (now wrote them as well) in the post but none of it seems to work .evrything works even the browser loads the .css file as so the problem isnt in the html file or css file.The problem is that the browser is not applying the css styling after getting hold of the .css file as you can see in the last picture i uploaded
